# Count facts in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a base of knowledge in a Prolog file (.pl) using SWI-Prolog.

```
reserve(bus(2389),place(4),datetravel([12,2,1999]),
      info([88032454321,robert,downe])).
reserve(bus(2389),place(33),datetravel([12,2,1999]),
      info([88032454321,alberto,perez])).
reserve(bus(2389),place(16),datetravel([12,2,1999]),
      info([88032454321,angel,clark])).
reserve(bus(4566),place(17),datetravel([22,3,2005]),
      info([88032454321,don,self])).
reserve(bus(2389),place(22),datetravel([12,2,1999]),
      info([88032454321,singmud,dante])).
```

I implemented a rule that ye gave me several parameters count the number of events that comply with these restrictions, but does not work for me, as I can?

Rule

```
test(N,D,M,Y,P):-
   reserve(bus(N),place(4),datetravel([D,M,Y]),
           info([88032454321,robert,downe])),
   test(N,D,M,Y,P+1).
```

Question

```
?- test(2389,12,2,1999,P).
```

Given my question the rule should return the number 4.

Comment: You can't pass `P+1` and expect Prolog to evaluate the expression. It doesn't work that way. it will literally pass the term, `'+'(P,1)` to the predicate.And you don't have a base case for `test` that handles the trivial case. With just one recursive predicate, when would you expect it to end? And then with each call to `test`, Prolog will keep matching the same fact to the rule you have (since a new predicate call starts at the beginning for matching facts/rules on a query), so that won't properly count them

Comment: The simplest way to count them would be to use `findall` then take the length of the result: `findall( _, reserve(bus(_), place(4), datetravel([_,_,_]), info([88032454321, robert,downe])), L), length(L, N).` and then `N` is the count.

Comment: I fully understand that I have to stop the case, recursion is so. I do not like to use a predefined function as findAll, I make it myself. I searched the implementation of findall on the network but can not find it, any ideas? I do it myself but not to start.

Comment: not really something as specific interests me more power to implement something myself, but where to start? It occurs to me to save each value of P in a list and then see its length, would be fine as well?

Comment: Googling "SWI prolog source" gives yields the link to the SWI "build from source" page. To get the source for `findall/3` from SWI's implementation, you can download the [SWI source](http://www.swi-prolog.org/build/).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at library([aggregate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate)).

It's powerful and worth to study.

```
:- use_module(library(aggregate)). % optional, this library is autoloaded
test(N,D,M,Y,P):-
      aggregate_all(count, reserve(bus(N),place(4),datetravel([D,M,Y]),info([88032454321,robert,downe])), P).
```

test/5 is just a placeholder for a query... actually, your data model isn't easy to interface. Since Prolog data model is *relational*, you should try to apply techniques similar to those employed designing SQL databases.

Comment: I can not use (aggregate all), I implement myself, any ideas?

Comment: I knew about `aggregate_all` with `count`, but it was faster to just Google for the proper syntax which brought me here.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of how you could count facts assuming there's a unique key. This example just has a simple fact, `foo/1` with one argument, which is the unique key. What I have here is a simple framework. I'll leave it as an exercise to make it work for your case, which is very straightforward.

Also, given that you want to write the code from more fundamental principles, I'll leave writing `member/2` as an exercise as well.

```
foo(a).
foo(b).
foo(c).

count(Thing, N) :-
    count(Thing, [], 0, N).

count(Thing, Seen, Acc, N) :-
    call(Thing, X),
    (   member(X, Seen)
    ->  fail
    ;   !,
        Acc1 is Acc + 1,
        count(Thing, [X|Seen], Acc1, N)
    ).
count(_, _, N, N).
```

Here's how it's called. You can hard-code your fact functor in `count/2,4` if you wish. Here, you'd just replace `call(Thing, X)` with `foo(X)` and get rid of the `Thing` argument altogether. But in this case, I decided to make the fact functor an argument:

```
| ?- count(foo, N).

N = 3

yes
| ?-
```

Actually, `count` can provide the entire list of evaluated facts if you wish. You would just include it as an extra accumulator argument. It's already collected in `Seen`.

Comment: I modified my judgment this. `test(N,D,M,Y,P):-reserve(bus(N),place(4),datetravel([D,M,Y]),info([88032454321,robert,downe])), add_list(P,L1,L2),len(L2,R).` I think it will not work well but I do not want to complicate even with a solution like yours, how can I follow?

Comment: @user1813375 are you having trouble adopting my solution to your problem? It should be straight forward. The problem with your suggestion is that `add_list` has a singleton variable `L1` (doesn't appear anywhere else), and it will not be able to continually update `L2`. Once a variable is instantiated within a predicate, it cannot be changed except through backtracking.

Comment: @user1813375 as I suggested in my comment to your original post, you can look up the source code for `findall/3` for other ideas. `findall/3` uses `assertz` and `retract` to accomplish what it does.

Comment: `test(N,D,M,Y,P,L1):-reserve(bus(N),place(4),datetravel([D,M,Y]),info([88032454321,robert,downe])),addl(1,L1,L2),len(L2,P),test(N,D,M,Y,P,L2).`... Well, I provide the empties and fills in list, and do backtraking sending the new list and the same search, but nothing ..¿?

Comment: everything simply has to be provided by me.

Comment: @user1813375 what does `addl/3` do? How is `P` initialized? How is its value finally determined? The solution I provided resolves these issues. Are you having trouble adopting it to your problem? `member/2` is easy to write.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97022/discussion-between-user1813375-and-lurker).